# how do manipulation with time in go?

Tags: go, time

I parsed the time to variable

```
input := "" 
fmt.Scan(&input)
t, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, input)
```

and now I need to change the day in the date, as given below

```
t.Day() = t.Day() + 1
```

of course, this example generated an error, so maybe somebody know how do it correct7 help me please

Comment: You can do `t=t.AddDate(0,0,1)` or `t=t.Add(time.Hour*24)`. It's all documented [here](https://golang.org/pkg/time/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi the go time package provides 2 methods for this

1. [Add(Duration)](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Add)

   time.Add(24 * time.Hour)
2. [AddDate(years int, months int, days int)](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.AddDate)

   time.AddDate(0,0,1)

With this you can use negative values to go back and positive to go forward